# custom string sort comparison function weird behavior

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to sort a vector of strings, however its not a strait forward sorting. I wrote a custom sort function which works perfectly for smaller vector sizes (<100 element), however I get really weird behavior with larger sizes. Note: the values input are all numbers.

I added some debug printf statements to see what was happening internally which is where I found that empty strings and other strange strings are being passed into the function to be sorted.

My expectation is that only the values in the vector will be passed into the function. I verified that vector is filled with known values.

Sorting function:

```
bool sortFunc( string a, string b ){    
    printf( "a: %s,\tb: %s  \t", a.c_str(), b.c_str() );

    //sorting magic defining 'bool retVal'

    printf( "%s goes before %s\n", retVal?a.c_str():b.c_str(), retVal?b.c_str():a.c_str() );

    return retVal;
}
```

Main function:

```
vector<string> a(n);
for( int i=0; i<n; ++i ){
    cin >> a[i];
}

sort(a.begin(),a.end(),sortFunc);
```

Sample of weird output:

```
a: 2,   b: 10   2 goes before 10
a: 10,  b: 10   10 goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: \240E,   b: 10   \240E goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: {@,  b: 10   {@ goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: ,    b: 10    goes before 10
a: \225E,   b: 10   10 goes before \225E
a: 2,   b: 10   2 goes before 10
a: 10,  b: \225E    10 goes before \225E
a: ,    b:       goes before 
a: ,    b:       goes before 
a: \245E,   b:       goes before \245E
a: \236E,   b: \245E    \245E goes before \236E
a: 0G\260\377, b: \236E    0G\260\377 goes before \236E
a: 0G\260\377, b: \245E    0G\260\377 goes before \245E
a: 0G\260\377, b:      0G\260\377 goes before
```

Comment: (A) Why are you accepting the strings by value? (B) The sort algorithm may very welly have a scratch space to move strings in and out of. Moving a string would leave it in some unknown but valid state. (C) Did it occur to you that your "magic" may not be a strict weak ordering, like the sort algorithm expects? Leaving the code with undefined behavior.

Comment: What if you print your `vector<string> a` before you sort it? Are you sure there are no "weird" values in it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you get the output "10 goes before 10" because `retVal` is true (it's impossible to tell from the output), you don't have a strict weak ordering and the result is undefined.

Comment: @xander, I do print it before as well as inspect the variable in Xcode

Comment: @molbdnilo, how are you supposed to handle the case where a and b are equal?

Comment: @StoryTeller, i modified the function to pass by reference which resolved the issues with the weird strings (i.e. "0G\260\377,"), however I still have empty strings being passed in/operated on.

Comment: @SmittyMcSmith If the elements are considered equal, the comparison should return `false`, since neither is ordered before the other. (If you were sorting numbers, `<` and `>` would be fine, but not `<=`or `>=`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo that solved the remaining issue! However, I don't understand why it should return false. `The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second` ...doesn't that say that `return 1` means to not change order and `return 0` means to change order?

Comment: @SmittyMcSmith You should return `true` if and only if you consider `a` to be "before" `b`. If `b` is "before" `a`, if you consider them equal, or if you can't say, you return `false`. You should not assume that the arguments already have some kind of order that can be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `std::sort` acts funny, it's almost always because of an invalid comparison function. The comparison function that you pass to `std::sort` must provide a **strict weak ordering**. The usual failure is that the comparison function is defined such that for two objects `a` and `b`, `compare(a,b)` returns true **and** `compare(b,a)` returns true, i.e., `a` comes before `b` and `b` comes before `a`. When that happens, the sort algorithm may well run off the end of your data and do all sorts of wild and crazy things.

The actual answer to this question lies somewhere inside this:

```
//sorting magic defining 'bool retVal'
```